# How to have a publisher continue even after timeout?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

So I am making multiple API calls that I need to refresh my UI. I am using CombineLatest to wait until I have data from all of them before updating the UI:

```
let apiCall1 = repository1.fetchData().eraseToAnyPublisher()
let apiCall2 = repository2.fetchData().eraseToAnyPublisher()
let apiCall3 = repository3.fetchData().eraseToAnyPublisher()
let apiCall4 = repository4.fetchData().eraseToAnyPublisher()

Publishers.CombineLatest4(apiCall1, apiCall2, apiCall3, apiCall4)
      .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .finished: return
            case .failure(_): handleError()
            }
      }, receiveValue: { [weak self] result1, result2, result3, result4 in
            self.saveResults(result1, result2, result3, result4)
            self.updateUI()
      })
      .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Three are vital, but `apiCall4` should be optional. If it takes too long, I would like to avoid waiting for it. In other words, I don't want to block the UI until it comes in.

So I am trying to implement a stop gap timeout. Maybe return an empty array so that I can update the UI until I actually get the data.

I have played with adding a timeout to the publisher, something like this:

```
let apiCall4 = repository4.fetchData().eraseToAnyPublisher() 
.timeout(5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, customError: {
    return ResponseError.timeout
})
.replaceError(with: [])
```

But the problem, of course, is that this terminates the `apiCall4` publisher. I won't get the data if the API call completes after the timeout.

Is there any way to send a placeholder value after x amount of time without actually terminating the `apiCall4` publisher?

Comment: Put the timeout inside a flatmap so you can turn failure into a value without terminating the actual publisher?

Comment: See the Failing Without Terminating section of my https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html

Comment: Thank you @matt I will give it a shot. And that is a very helpful resource! I am bookmarking it.

Comment: So I am not sure this covers my use case - it seems like the code in your example terminates the publisher that I want to add the timeout to instead of allowing it to continue. I need it to continue after replacing the timeout error with empty data so that I eventually do get the data I requested. 

The example allows the combined publisher to continue without throwing an error, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Understood! Sorry if it's not as useful as I hoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is:

- If `apiCall4` publishes its first output before the timeout, you only want the genuine outputs from `apiCall4`.
- If `apiCall4` doesn't publish its first output before the timeout, you want to publish a default value, but you want to allow `apiCall4` to continue running, and use its output if it eventually publishes anything.

Here's one way to solve this.

- We'll use a `Just` with a `delay` to publish the default output after the timeout.
- We'll use `map` to tag the default output and the genuine outputs, so we can distinguish them downstream.
- We'll use `merge` to combine the tagged outputs of `apiCall4` and the delayed `Just` into a single stream.
- We'll then use `scan` to keep some state about whether we've ever seen a genuine output, so if we get the default output after seeing a genuine output, we can discard the default output.
- Since `scan` publishes its entire state, and always publishes when its upstream publishes, we can't actually discard the default output in `scan`, nor can we publish **just** the output without the extra state. So we'll use `compactMap` after `scan` to strip off `scan`s extra state and actually discard if we get the default output after a genuine output.

Here's the type we'll use to tag each output with its genuine-ness:

```
fileprivate struct Wrapper<Output> {
    var output: Output
    var isGenuine: Bool
}
```

And here's the type we'll use to hold the extra `scan` state:

```
fileprivate struct ScanState<Output> {
    var output: Output?
    var hasSeenGenuine: Bool = false
}
```

And here's how we assemble the pieces, as described above:

```
extension Publisher {
    func defaulting<S: Scheduler>(
        to defaultOutput: Output,
        after timeout: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
        scheduler: S
    ) -> some Publisher<Output, Failure> {
        let genuine = self
            .map { Wrapper(output: $0, isGenuine: true) }

        let defaulted = Just(Wrapper(
            output: defaultOutput,
            isGenuine: false
        ))
            .setFailureType(to: Failure.self)
            .delay(for: timeout, scheduler: scheduler)

        return genuine.merge(with: defaulted)
            .scan(ScanState<Output>()) { state, wrapper in
                if state.hasSeenGenuine && !wrapper.isGenuine {
                    return ScanState(output: nil, hasSeenGenuine: true)
                } else {
                    return ScanState(
                        output: wrapper.output,
                        hasSeenGenuine: wrapper.isGenuine || state.hasSeenGenuine
                    )
                }
            }
            .compactMap { $0.output }
    }
}
```

Here's a test function:

```
func runTest(call4Delay: DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride) -> AnyCancellable {
    let apiCall1 = Just("answer1").delay(for: .milliseconds(300), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    let apiCall2 = Just("answer2").delay(for: .milliseconds(400), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    let apiCall3 = Just("answer3").delay(for: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    let apiCall4 = Just("answer4").delay(for: call4Delay, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)

    let defaultedCall4 = apiCall4.defaulting(to: "default", after: .milliseconds(1000), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)

    let combo = apiCall1.combineLatest(apiCall2, apiCall3, defaultedCall4)
    let ticket = combo.sink { print($0) }
    return ticket
}
```

The timeout is one second. If I run a test with `apiCall4` publishing after 900 milliseconds, I only see the genuine output:

```
("answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4")
```

If I run a test with `apiCall4` publishing after 1100 milliseconds, I see the default output followed by the genuine output:

```
("answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "default")
("answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4")
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! This is exactly what I have been trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

> Three are vital, but apiCall4 should be optional. If it takes too long, I would like to avoid waiting for it. In other words, I don't want to block the UI until it comes in... Maybe return an empty array so that I can update the UI until I actually get the data.

The answer is simple, just `prepend` an empty array to apiCall4. The UI will update when the other three values emit along with the empty array for apiCall4, then when apiCall4 comes in, the UI will update again with the additional, optional, information.

No need for a timeout at all.

> Is there any way to send a placeholder value after x amount of time without actually terminating the apiCall4 publisher?

The best part about using prepend is that the UI will update as soon as the other three calls emit values. If apiCall4 has already emitted by then, the default won't show, if not, then it will.

### Update

I didn't know you want to force the user to wait 5 seconds... Here is a simple solution for that:

```
let call4 = apiCall4.amb(Just([]).delay(for: .seconds(5), scheduler: RunLoop.main, options: .none)
Publishers.CombineLatest4(apiCall1, apiCall2, apiCall3, call4)
```

The `amb` operator will take from whichever publisher emits first. The second publisher (`Just([]).delay...`) will emit after 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great suggestion, however, not quite what I am looking for. This will immediately give me an empty array without giving the API a chance to come through first. I want to wait 5 seconds before temporarily giving up and using an empty array.

Comment: Well it won't be immediate. It will only emit after the other three publishers have finished getting their information. Do you really want to force the user to wait 5 seconds even when the data is available? If Combine had the `amb` operator, then you could just `amb(apiCall4, .just([]).delay(.seconds(5))`. I just learned, the amb operator is in the CombineExt library.

Comment: Updated my answer using CombineExt